# Can we have an internal messaging system?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, private-messaging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A way to leave messages to users?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/a-way-to-leave-messages-to-users)

Can we have a way to send a message or email directly to someone without having to do it via a comment, question, answer or chat? Or is they a way already?

It would also be useful to have a forum. If a question is not relevant to the Q&A site may be it could just be moved to a forum. I fact a relevant question might come from a forum topic and it could be useful o have a link between the too.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why these things would be useful?

Comment: I have an example.  I enjoyed a long discussion with a user in a comment thread, followed the link to his profile, and found he shares many of my interests.  I really wanted to invite him to an online RPG I'm running, but could find no way to do so that was appropriate (a meta post?  A comment having nothing to do with the topic being discussed?) and private enough (to give out my email, the link to my campaign, etc.)  While I understand SE's intent to provide access to the questions and answers, sometimes you meet people that way.  I still wish I could find a way...

Answer (score 7):

NO.

This has been [requested repeatedly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) and denied every single time by Stack Exchange Inc, and other users of SO/SE sites.

The reason is simple. We are here to interact with the content, not the people. The chat system allows for some direct conversation with people, but it is always public (except in very specific circumstances related to moderation). Comments are intentionally kept clean. The focus of SE sites is on content, not interaction, that's why there is not a PM system and won't ever be one.

As far as a forum goes...why? I see absolutely no need (unless you're looking for play by post....then just set up a gallery chat room..

Comment: Y'know, it might be profitable to ally with one of the big forums. We could direct people to the forum for forum-style discussions, they could direct people here for expert Q&A.